# Plots not displaying in R after I call them

Tags: r, plot

I have recently been going through some of the modules on Software Carpentry's "Programming in R" lesson, and I have experienced problems displaying some of my plots in RStudio.
Here is the link to the site:
http://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-inflammation/04-cond/index.html

Here is the page with the download link for the inflammation data files (r-novice-inflammation-data.zip) if necessary:
http://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-inflammation/setup.html

And the practice problem that I am on is called "Choosing Plots Based on Data"

I was supposed to create a function that creates a box plot or stripchart for a file on patient inflammation data based on whether the vector of that data that is called meets a certain threshold. Here is my code:

```
dat <- read.csv(file = "data/inflammation-01.csv", header = FALSE)
plot_dist <- function(x, threshold) {
  if (length(x) > threshold) {
    boxplot(x)
  } else {
    stripchart(x)
  }
}
plot_dist(dat[, 10], threshold = 10)
```

When I call the function, however, no plots are displayed. I went to the plots section in Rstudio, but still found no plots. On my console, the output after calling this function is something like:

Does anyone have any ideas why my plots aren't being displayed? I don't think there is anything wrong with the function, since I don't get any errors after calling it, it just doesn't plot anything. Thanks much!

Comment: Does `dev.list()` show anything? Have you been writing to files with `pdf()` or `png()`? Does the problem persist if you restart R? Are you sure the command is being run? (you could add a "print()" in there to check)

Comment: Also, are there any errors or warnings displayed in the console? (e.g. "finite values for xlim required")

Comment: Looks like it was nothing more than a simple restart to fix the issue! Always nice when that's the problem. If it occurs again, I'll take the other options into consideration. Thanks for the help!